# Accurev undo a revert to basis

Tags: revert, accurev, purge, basis

In Accurev I have accidently purge a stream by doing a revert to basis while trying to pull the latest from the stream. This removed all the files within the stream. Is it possible to undo it? and how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AccuRev doesn't have a command to revert a revert operation, but the following workaround will allow you to restore these elements.

1. Create a new stream off the stream where the purge occurred and set the time stamp to 1 second before the purge operation.
2. From the new stream, perform a change pallet into the stream that had the purge.
3. Select the elements that were purged and promote them back into the stream.